# How to add validation using expressjs for cgpa

Tags: node.js, validation, express

```
req.checkBody('cgpa','cgpa is required').notEmpty();
```

I need to add a validation to cgpa to check that cgpa must be less than 4 . how should I do that ?
I am using expressjs validator 
Thankyou .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **express-validator**'s [`custom(validator)`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator#usage)

> The custom validator may also throw JavaScript exceptions (eg throw new Error()) and return falsy values to indicate the field is invalid.

You can mount it like any other express middleware

```
'use strict';

let http = require('http');
let express = require('express');

let app = express();
let bp = require('body-parser');

app.use(bp.json());
app.use(bp.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));

let server = http.createServer(app);
const {check, validationResult} = require('express-validator/check');

const PORT = 8888;
server.listen(PORT, () => {

  console.log(`Server is up at ${PORT}`);

  app.post('/foo', [

    check('cgpa').exists().custom((value) => {
      return value < 4;
    }).withMessage('CGPA should be less than 4')

  ], (req, res) => {

    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(422).json({
        errors: errors.mapped()
      });
    }

    return res.status(200).send({
      msg: 'Hello world'
    });
  });

});
```

If the cgpa is < 4, the response will be

> {
>       "msg": "Hello world"
>   }

If the cgpa is > 4, the response will be an error

> {
>       "errors": {
>           "cgpa": {
>               "location": "body",
>               "param": "cgpa",
>               "value": 43,
>               "msg": "CGPA should be less than 4"
>           }
>       }
>   }